Where does this upper bound relating the $T$ count and $H$ count come from?
I am reading this paper on optimisation of the Hadamard gate count (Optimal Hadamard Gate count for Clifford + $T$ synthesis of Pauli rotations sequences). The idea of the paper is to optimise the number of Hadamard gates in a Clifford + $T$ circuits as pre-processing for $T$ count optimisation. Such optimisations are motivated by a desire to reduce the number of ancilla qubits required for the compilation workflow.
I watched a recorded talk by one of the authors where this bound is cited.
Every $n$ qubit Clifford + $T$ circuit can be optimised so that
$$
\tau \leq \frac{(n+1)(n+2h)}{2} + 1\,.
$$
Where $\tau$ is the number of $T$ gates and $h$ is the number of internal $H$ gates (internal meaning Hadamard gates which are between the first and last non-Clifford gate in the circuit).
As far as I can tell a quadratic upper bound is established in the paper T-count optimization and Reed-Muller codes (see section 4.1 theorem 4.3). The bound for $\tau$ is stated as $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.
Is there some useful intuition on how this bound is derived?
